# How to obtain text that has its width constrained to the width of the browser window?

Tags: html, css

What I want to achieve is text that has its width constrained to the width of the window regardless of the zoom level/font sizes, and automatically redimension as I change window width. The end goal is to understand a general approach for how to do that for every site that I want to read.

For example, at stackoverflow.com if you zoom in with `<command> + <+>/<ctrl> + <+>`, the width of the text increases together with font sizes/images, and pretty soon the text is wider than the screen.

But I would rather simply have the text adjust to the size of the window, so I can choose the width by simply redimensioning the browser window.

So, I guess what I am trying to ask is...

What should I be looking for when attempting to achieve that in a webpage?
What html elements/css properties should one pay attention to ?

Initially, I was thinking about creating styles that can be used with Stylish to achieve this. Perhaps there's another way?

EDIT:Solution, in accordance to @Vipin Mohan suggestion. I just put the following code in a Stylish style and activated it for SO

```
p, li{
    width: 80vw; /* adjust for website/personal preference */
    text-align: justify;
}

p + p {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

NOTE: my simple solution isn't perfect by any means, as it leaves SO's interface a bit mangled, such as missing buttons at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for its viewport percentage length.

The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the intial containing block . When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly

The values are:

- vw (% of the viewport width) vh (% of the viewport height)
- vi (1% of
  the viewport size in the direction of the root element's inline axis)
- vb (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's
  block axis)
- vmin (the smaller of vw or vh)
- vmax (the larger
  or vw or vh)

1 v* is equal to 1% of the initial containing block.

Example `font-size: 1vw`
Assuming that width of your monitor is 1000px, and browser is maximized, then 1vw =10px. Should your window size be decreased to 500px, then 1vw = 5px and so.

As you can see, when the viewport width increases, so does the font-size, without needing to use media queries.

These values are a sizing unit, just like pxor em, so they can be used to size other elements as well, such was width, margin, or padding.

Browser support is pretty good. You rarely need a fallback these days, as most people use browser versions atleast 2010 or later.

Comment: This works.

I thought it was going to be more complicated than that, such as understanding more complicated rules about interaction between html elements, inheritance behavior, etc. so I spent some hours doing that.

But creating some simple style rules for `p` elements is good enough for solving the purpose of the thread. I just put the following code in a Stylish style and activated it for SO.

Comment: Glad it helped. All the same if you are using too small a size in large screens, i recommend using @media and screen for setting a minimum font size value